# Positioning the dialog at position defined by javascript variables

Tags: primefaces

How to position the primefaces `dialog` dynamically at x,y co-ordinates *defined by javascript variables* ?

**My attempt:-**

I tried doing that through javascript itself but I failed to set the position through following code:

```
        var dialog_x=300;
        var dialog_y=500;

        var s = document.getElementById("dialogId"); 
        s.style.position = "relative";
        s.style.left = dialog_x + "px";
        s.style.top = dialog_y + "px";
```

Note that this dialogId is what I defined in the id attribute of dialog. As I came to know that id of parent container are also appended to this id, I also tried using the resultant id(after append) but it doesnt work.

## **Edit:**

I figured out that dialog container(which contains the header and the content of the dialog) which I expected to be assigned the id that I defined through id attribute on dialog component is not assigned any id which was the reason why I could not access the dialog. I still cannot understand how I should go about retrieving this element when it has not been assigned any id. The id that I defined was infact assigned to the dialog content container inside of the main dialog container.

Comment: Perhaps of setting it to relative `s.style.position = "relative";
` you can try setting to to absolute, `s.style.position = "absolute";`?

Comment: tried doing that as well, but i guess the probelm is that I am not even able to retrieve the dialog element in the javascript with the Id that I assigned to it

Comment: It sounds like you have more basic problems.  If you do not downloaded and installed the Firebug plugin for Firefox I highly recommend you do so.  With it you will be able to search for elements on the DOM and be able to find the actual Id of the dialog.

Comment: yes I have that. and I tried retrieving the dialog with id that I saw over there but doesnt work

Comment: Stop and think about what you just wrote.  You essentially claim that `document.getElementById` did not work correctly.  The only reason for this is if you are passing the WRONG id.  Perhaps there are more than one DOM element with the same id.  You need to more closely inspect what the dialogId is and what you are passing to `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jQuery`, you can call a `javascript` method that will adjust the positionning of the dialog when the dialog will show.

```
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:commandButton value="Select Location" oncomplete="TreeDialog.show()" id="selectLocationButton"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Select the location" id="treeDialog"
            widgetVar="TreeDialog"
            modal="true" onShow="adjustPositionning($('#selectLocationButton'), $('#treeDialog'))" width="450">
        <p:tree value="#{myController.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="true">  
        <p:treeNode>  
            <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />  
        </p:treeNode>  
        </p:tree>  
    </p:dialog>

<script type="text/javascript">
function adjustPositionning(sourceElement, dialog) {
    var x = sourceElement.offset().left;
    var y = sourceElement.offset().top;
    var width = sourceElement.width();
    var padding = 15;
  dialog.parent().offset({ top: y, left: x + width + padding });
}
</script>
```